# Uploadify SWF plugin stops upload when hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, uploadify

I've notices that when you have [Uploadify SWF plugin](http://www.uploadify.com/documentation/) inside a div and then you hide it and show again, it reloads. That's a bit anoying because:

- it stops current upload
- it resets its internal file id (I have some login tied to it)

I could probably put Uploadify into some floating div and just set `visibility: hidden` but I hope there's some better solution.

Have anyone experienced the same thing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set the height to 0
or position it absolute to a non visible area
or use sth like tabs or accordions to hide it.